# Multiple Command Output to single file

Tags: command-line

I’m trying to put output of multiple commands into single file. This is how I have it working now, but I’m trying to shorten the syntax and mention the output file only once. Any idea?

Ipconfig >> c:\text.text && arp -a >> c:\text.txt && netstat -anb >> c:\text.txt

Ipconfig >> c:\text.text && arp -a >> c:\text.txt && netstat -anb >> c:\text.txt